# Trouble finding the max value in python

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I am trying to find the day with the highest percentage. For some reason my output keeps coming out as Week 2 wednesday as the highest percentage. Here is the output I am trying to get:

Here are the other lists in main

`pieces = [10, 14, 15, 12, 20, 18, 17, 9, 23, 21, 20, 16, 17, 22]
    defects = [ 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 5, 2, 7, 4, 8, 5, 6, 9]`

`list1, percentlist = ['Wk 1 Monday', 'Wk 1 Tuesday', 'Wk 1 Wednesday', 'Wk 1 
    Thursday', 'Wk 1 Friday', 'Wk 1 Saturday', 'Wk 1 Sunday', 'Wk 2 Monday', 'Wk 
    2 Tuesday', 'Wk 2 Wednesday', 'Wk 2 Thursday', 'Wk 2 Friday', 'Wk 2 
    Saturday', 'Wk 2 Sunday'] ,[]`

```
for index in range(0, len(pieces)):
    percent = (defects[index]/pieces[index])
    percentlist.append(percent * 100)        
print("***************************************")
print("The highest percent of defects per piece: ", 
format(max(percentlist),'.2f'),'%')
print("Occured on: \t\t\t", max(list1))
print("***************************************")
```

Comment: Your precent calculated from "percent = (defects[index]/pieces[index])" will always get zero, because it's integer calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `max(list1)` is causing this problem.

You need to be telling your program that you want the index corresponding to the max value in `percentlist`. This can be done as follows:

```
index = percentlist.index(max(percentlist)) # add this line
print("Occured on: \t\t\t", list1[index]) # modify your existing line
```